# AWS LEX menu based chat bot

Tags: amazon-web-services, chatbot, amazon-lex

I am trying to create a chatbot with AWS Lex. The chatbot should have menu based responses and when a user selects an option the bot then continues the conversation based on the selected item.

Example conversation:

**user:** can you tell me the weather

**bot:** which city do you live in 
A. London 
B. New York 
C. Mumbai 
D. Tokyo

**user:** C

**bot:** The weather in Mumbai is .....

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: What slot and slot type should I use and how I add logic to get city name from selected letter (eg get Mumbai from letter C)

Comment: A suggestion would be to use one of Lex's demo bots that includes Lambda functions to help drive the Bot's behaviour. This will answer your question of how to build a bot, what slots are and how to use them and how to use Lambda's to control behaviour. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/gs-bp-create-bot.html